# Adding a custom font in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, resources, custom-font, xamarin.essentials

According to this post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/

The new way to add a custom font is to add the font as an embeddedResource and then add this line in App.xaml.ca:

```
[assembly: ExportFont("DSEG7ModernRegular.ttf")]
```

But I get this error:

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ExportFontAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

My project references:

- Xamarin.Essentials (1.3.1)
- Xamarin.Forms (4.4.0.991265)  - 4.5
- NetStandard.Library (2.0.3)

Comment: "In this post we will see how to use it in Xamarin.Forms **4.5.530** and up."

Comment: So... where that version then???????

Comment: I'm going to assume that's a typo and he means **4.5.0.530** - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/4.5.0.530

Comment: Updated to 4.5.0.617 and still the same problem...Weird ...

Comment: it's in the release notes for that build - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.5/4.5.0-sr4#embedded-fonts.  It should be in the main Xamarin.Forms namespace - I assume you have `using Xamarin.Forms;` in the file?  You might try the usual tricks of restarting VS, clearing bin/obj folders, etc

Comment: @Jason, that fix my problem... Can you write an answer? I forgot to add a using... Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExportFontAttribute` is in the `Xamarin.Forms` namespace, so be sure you have

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
```